Blender Geometry Nodes Dissolve Effect - More Natural Falloff for Proximity Effect?
i'm attempting to make a dissolve effect that is driven by proximity to an Empty.
So far, i've created a mesh to volume, then populated that with points/instances of a brick.  I have the Empty shrinking the brick instances when in close proximity to the Empty.
The problem is that it looks too organized, perfect, and unnatural.
So, how do I make the falloff of this affect less like a perfect sphere, and more random/natural?
This is my first attempt, with an additional translation effect applied (that i'm still working on getting right, plesase see my other posts):

Here is my node setup:

Thanks!  There are other effects im trying for related to this topic that impact this one, but Stack Exchange wouldn't let me include them all in one post, despite them being relevant. Please see my post history if you're curious and want to help out.
Thank you!

What about multiplying the output of the Map Range node with the Fac output of a Noise texture before plugging it into the Scale Instances node? Or even earlier, multiplying the Distance result with noise?

I will give this a shot and let you know how it works, thanks!

Multiplying noise with the distance created a cool result! Thanks!

Here again as a proper answer: try multiplying the Distance result with the Fac output of a Noise Texture and play with the values to your liking. You can also multiply the noise before plugging it into the multiplication of the Distance.

Multiplying the noise with values > 1 reduces the effect, here I multiply it with 3:

Values < 1 cause utter chaos ;) This is 0.7:

